# R how to change shape/size of plots save as pngs

Tags: r

I am trying to change the size/shape of the base plots in R so they are larger and have closer to a rectangular shape than a square shape at default. Here is an example of one of my plots:

```
  png(file.path("plots",sets[set],"rspGREKM_vs_Star_Age.png"))
  plot(x=ages, y=growth.rates, main=paste(sets[set],"rspGREKM vs Star Age",sep=" "), pch=3, col="purple",
        xlab=expression("Star Age (days)"), ylab=expression("rspGREKM"))
  dev.off()
```

I tried including `dev.new(width=5, height=4)`, but there was no noticeable change. What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `png()` has arguments for defining the width and height of the graphics device, as well as an extra argument for entering the desired units of those dimensions. Check `args(png)` or `?png`.

here is a reproducible example, the first part will produce a rectangular plot, while the second part will produce the default square-shaped plot.

```
data("mtcars")
##rectangular plot
png("p1.png", width = 640, height = 420, units = "px")
plot(mtcars$mpg, type="l",  main = "p1" )
dev.off()
## default plot
png("p2.png")
plot(mtcars$mpg, type="l", main = "p2" )
dev.off()
```